# Maven dependency management in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm currently building apps for Apache Spark. Spark provides during runtime a lot of dependencies, which I normally need if I test/run the apps locally in the IDE (IntelliJ).

Is there any possibility to have different set of dependendencies related if I use the 'package' or the usual compile/run target in IntelliJ ?

For instance, this is a needed dependency to Hadoop

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

But the scope 'provided' does not work when I run it locally in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want IntelliJ to use its [own build process](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/build-process.html) rather than Maven's, it's probably better to tell [add a (global) library to your project dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d2103330e263) in the IDE.

It definitely *won't* be providing these Spark JARs by default, which is what you're telling Maven here.

Comment: ok, so there is now way to do this in Maven if I understood you correctly?

Comment: Well, looks like you've done the Maven bit. If you want to _run_ it with Maven, you could either use the command line, combined with however you set up the Spark runtime, or you can [create a Maven run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-maven-run-debug-configuration.html) from IntelliJ to do the same thing, again making sure Spark dependencies are available to that JVM.